# Stating there's still room for a better answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

A lot of questions asked here are such that even if a good answer is found, it probably can still be enhanced.

On occasion, it makes sense to accept the best answer, but still it's quite probable that someone could (even easily) write a better one. A good example of this is [Biblical basis for the separation of church and state](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/278/biblical-basis-for-the-separation-of-church-and-state). Almost anyone who personally uses the Bible to argue for the separation of church and state could probably write a more in-depth answer. Still, the current best answer is good enough for now.

Should there be a way to request further answers, or is it just common sense that any 5-year-old question can be dug up and reanswered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think there is a better answer out there for your question you don't have accept an answer. Especially right now when we only have a user base of at most 200+ people its prudent to wait even a few days or weeks before you accept an answer when you know a better on exists.

If you want new answers you can place a bounty on your question. This allows you to say "Hey, this question needs a better answer, authors come back and improve or post a new answer." However it requires buy in from you, you have to be willing to give up the amount of rep you are offering (minimum 50).

Another option, if you know there is a better answer: Go find it. Do your own research and post the answer then accept it.

These are the best ways to get a better answer on an older question.

One last thing. If you want a better answer and your post is buried find a way to make an edit. Preferably something substantial (add an update of your own research or a clarification) not just a gramAr edit or something.